# How to turn an object into a string array

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I am trying to turn an object with several values in a string array in Angular.

I am calling a REST API that gives me the object, but I could not managed to read the values into an array.

```
constructor(private httpService: HttpClient) { }
  arrayMessages: string[];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.httpService.get('http://localhost:8080/greetings?message=hello', {responseType: 'json'})
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.arrayMessages = data as string [];
          console.log(this.arrayMessages);
        }
  );
}
```

Comment: so you get this back [ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]?

Comment: That won't happen magically. You need to write some code. Suppose your object is `{ foo: { bar: 'hello' } }`. Now what should be in the string array? How could we know? How could that happen without you writing any code?

Comment: show us the mock of your response

Comment: post your dummy response and post your expected format

Comment: Yes, I get back e.g. ["string1", "string2"]. These two values are supposed to be in a string array

Comment: You get back `["string1", "string2"]` and what is the desired result. Example please.